# Correct way to git --force to a specific branch

Tags: git

I need to rebase a branch to a previous commit. I was able to rebase my local to the desired commit and now I need to push it to the remote.

My remote is (sommething like) `origin/bugfix/bug12345` and my local branch is `bugfix/bug12345`

I have checked several stackoverflow entries about force push, I read the advise to revert instead of rebase but I absolutelly need to rebase, but I don't want to screw anything else.

I tried:

`git push origin/bugfix/bug12345 bugfix/bug12345`

but I got this message:

```
fatal: 'origin/bugfix/bug12345' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

I read in another post to do:

`git push origin master`

BUT... that sounds like I am pushing to master and **I don't want to push to that branch**!

Can someone advice how to push to origin/bugfix/bug12345 **and only to that specific branch**?

Comment: FWIW I do a `git push —delete origin <branch>` followed by a `git push origin <branch>`. It works.

Answer (score 3):

The command would be

```
git push origin bugfix/bug12345:bugfix/bug12345
```

or if you were already checked out to that branch

```
git push -f
```

Answer (score 1):

You can checkout to local `bugfix/bug12345` branch then do force push to remote (origin) `bugfix/bug12345`.

```
$ git checkout bugfix/bug12345
$ git push -f origin bugfix/bug12345
```

**Or,** if your local branch is not `bugfix/bug12345` & want to force push remote's `bugfix/bug12345` branch, then follow:

```
$ git branch    
# local branch is 'master' or else instead of 'bugfix/bug12345' 

$ git push -f origin HEAD:bugfix/bug12345
# push the current branch without thinking about the local name
```

**N.B.:** `HEAD` is the reference of currently checked out commit (latest commit of current local branch)

Comment: I understand that git push -f origin bugfix/bug12345 would push branch  bugfix/bug12345 to origin. Could you please explain the syntax?

Comment: ok, `git push -f {remote} {branch-name}`. Checkout to the `bugfix/bug12345` branch then do Force push simply.

Comment: So.. {remote} is the remote branch, right? I still don't get why I push to "origin" if I want to push to a specific branch.

Comment: hi, `origin` is actually your remote repo's URL. If you want to push to a specific branch  follow: `git push -f origin HEAD:bugfix/bug12345`